# how to get out put in new paragraph on every function call

Tags: javascript

i am getting only last list  how can i get three lists 
I think fault is in

element . I tried to change it on every function call by a variable 'pid' so that i could get three list.
Can any body guide me 
code is as below regards,

```
<script>
var fruits = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fruits[i] = prompt("please enter the name of fruit " + (i + 1));

    }
    document.write("Fruits in unordered form are: " + fruits + "<br>");
function writeList (pid, heading, fruits) {
    var showList = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i <fruits.length; i++) {
        showList += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li><br>";       
        }
        showList += "</ul>";
    document.write("<p id='pid'></p>");     
    document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML = heading + " list of fruits is: <br>" + showList;
        }
writeList (1, "un sorted", fruits);
    fruits.sort();
    document.write("Fruits in ascending order are: "+ fruits + "<br>");
    writeList (2, "Sorted", fruits);
    fruits.reverse();
    document.write("Fruits in descending order are: " + fruits);
    writeList (3, "Descending", fruits);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#Notes)

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call.

and this is what [document.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) does

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it (see the
>   example above).

Also, id of an element has to be unique across the document.

`document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML` will always refer to only one element only.

simply replace

```
document.write ("<p id='pid'></p>")
```

with

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<p data-id='pid'></p>"
```

Similarly for other `document.write` replace with `document.body.innerHTML` version.

Also replace

```
document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML
```

with

```
document.querySelector("[data-id='pid']:last-child").innerHTML
```

Comment: I think id of an element  is changing because when function is called first time, id = 1 2nd time id is 2 & 3rd time, id = 3

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty space in the function call, change this:

```
writeList (1, "un sorted", fruits);
```

for this:

```
writeList(1, "un sorted", fruits);
```